# Maximum value for $x(t)$ in $x(t) = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + vt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In a book I am reading it says that the maximum value of $x(t)$ in $$x(t) = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + vt$$ is $\frac{v^2}{2g}$ and that this happens when $t=\frac{2v}{g}$

I cannot derive this though. When I try and get an expression for when the derivative of $x(t) = 0$ I end up with $t = \frac{v}{v'+g}$. How do you correctly calculate the expression where $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$?

Edit:

$0 = -\frac{1}{2}g * 2t + v + v'*t$

$0 = -gt + v + v' * t$

$t = \frac{v}{v'+g}$

I used the product rule on the right hand side of the equation as $v$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: What are you obtaining for the derivative of $x(t)$?

Comment: Evidently the speed is assumed to be a constant in this example.

Comment: The expression you gave is for the position of an object in vertical motion with an *initial* velocity $v$.  Velocity is not constant throughout the motion of the object, but the *initial velocity* is a constant.  (Usually it is denoted $v_0$ to avoid this conclusion.)

Answer (score 2):

$x'(t)=-gt+v$ then $x'(t)=0$ implies $-gt+v=0$ then $t=\displaystyle\frac{v}{g}$, and 
$x(\frac{v}{g})=-\frac{g}{2}(\frac{v}{g})^2+v\frac{v}{g}=\frac{v}{2g}$.

Comment: Well $v$ is a function of $t$ is it not? Ie. velocity...

Comment: In your notation you should be specific, when we write $v$, we suppose constant, if you want it is a function of $t$, you should write the equation as $v(t)$.

Comment: @csss There may be a typo/missing context in the formula you've been given; often this is written as $x(t) = -\frac12gt^2+v_0t+x_0$, where the subscripts on $v_0$ and $x_0$ are there to indicate that these are _initial_ ($t=0$) values - i.e., that they are constants.  If $v$ in the formula as written isn't a constant then the equation isn't a correct equation of motion.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring, $$-\frac g2t^2 + vt=\left(-\frac g2t+v\right)t$$
has roots at $t=0$ and $t=2v/g$.

By symmetry of the parabola, the apex lies midway, at $$t=\frac vg.$$

Answer (score 0):

No need for derivatives.

$$x(t)=-\frac g2t^2 + vt$$ can be rewritten as
$$-\frac g2\left(t^2-2\frac vgt\right)=-\frac g2\left(t^2-2\frac vgt+\frac{v^2}{g^2}\right)+\frac{v^2}{2g}=-\frac g2\left(t-\frac vg\right)^2+\frac{v^2}{2g}.$$

This function obviously reaches its maximum when the first term is $0$, i.e. $$t=\frac vg.$$
On that moment,
$$x(t)=\frac{v^2}{2g}.$$